# Optimize ldap connection latency

Tags: java, ldap

Ldap context initialization takes roughly 17 seconds for every request which is very high and not expected for our application. Therefore, I have initialized context once and using same context for every other request but I am getting connection reset exception.

Don't know if this was bad practice but to prevent the initialization from happening before every search I am making use of same context once it has been initialized. Here is the sample code:

```
private static volatile DirContext context ;

public synchronized static DirContext GetLdapDirContext() throws NamingException {

if(context != null) {
    return context;
}

Hashtable<String, Object> env = setLdapEnvironment();
context = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
return context;
```

}

```
    private static Hashtable<String, Object> setLdapEnvironment() {

Hashtable<String, Object> ldapEnvironment = new Hashtable<>(11);
ldapEnvironment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
ldapEnvironment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://ldap.amazon.com:636/");
ldapEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid=****,ou=ldap users,ou=infrastructure,o=amazon.com");
ldapEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
ldapEnvironment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

return ldapEnvironment;
```

}

Is there anyway to reduce latency ?
Will it be safe to make use of same context if it works ?

Comment: Depending on the keep alive duration on ldap server, you may get connection reset more  or less often. 17 seconds to make connection is extremely long. Typically the query is what takes long, not the connection. If the query is what takes time, consider caching the result, and only make the connect/requery if cached result is null or expired.